# Meaning of "Thank you for entertaining my application"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I found this line at the end of an application. What does it mean actually? When to use it?

> Thank you for entertaining my application.

Comment: In this context, entertain=consider.

Comment: I don't believe "entertaining an application" is idiomatic though; the verb "entertain", given this particular acceptation, seems to take on high-pitched connotations.

Comment: It's not a good match here. Use entertain in this sense for the abstract: an idea, a notion, a possibility. *I wouldn't even entertain that as a fantasy*. Goes to the general advice to use what you know (rather than looking stuff up in a dictionary and thinking you added value to your vocabulary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maker of the sentence may have meant the meaning of "consider/think about".

**about "entertain"**

1. invite sb to eat/drink with you

The Bradfords always entertained lavishly at Christmas.

They entertained us to lunch in their new house.

2. interest/amuse sb

Everyone was thoroughly entertained.

She entertained us with stories of her travels.

Phrases
~ and educate, ~ and enlighten, ~ and inform | keep sb ~ed

Films can entertain and educate, make you laugh or cry.

We hired a magician to keep the children entertained.

3. think about an idea/hope/feeling

I am amazed that such a crazy idea could be seriously entertained.

She would make no promises, but was willing to entertain the idea.

https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/14e59da17a2b4773a90bc214c11e9a63